# Having troubles with base case in a proof by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

show that if n is a positive integer and x is a real number larger than $-1$, then $(1+x)^{ n }\geq 1+nx\\ $

Proof by induction

Base case n=1

so $1+x = 1+x$

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume $(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$ for n>0 and x>-1
NTS $(1+x)^{n+1} \geq 1+(n+1)x=1+nx+x$

$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$
$(1+x)^{n+1} \geq (1+nx)(1+x)$ because $1+x$ is positive
$(1+x)^{n+1} \geq (1+nx^2+nx+x)$ but $nx^2$ is positive
so $1+nx^2+nx+x \geq 1+nx+x$

This implies that $(1+x)^{n+1} \geq 1+nx+x$

Comment: This is a typo in the question. It should be $$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$$

Comment: In particular, you always get 1 on both sides, if you plug in $x=0$, no matter how large $n$ is.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Now that you have the correct problem statement we encourage you to post an answer you own question! You can get feedback on your proof structure which helps a lot when you are just starting out in math.

Comment: I am done with the proof. I am going to post the solution

Answer (score 2):

Note that only in case $x=0,\forall n>1$ we can get equation.
Now  it must be shown that in case $n>1\quad x>-1$ there is a strict inequality $${ \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ n }>1+nx$$
in case $n=2$ it is obvious that $\\ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ 2 }=1+2x+{ x }^{ 2 }>1+2x$

Further,consider it is true for $n$,then

> $$\\ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ n+1 }={ \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ n }\left( 1+x \right) >\left( 1+nx \right) \left( 1+x \right) =\\ =1+x+nx+n{ x }^{ 2 }>1+nx+x=\left( n+1 \right) x\\ $$

P.S sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is the solution given along with the problem!!!

Comment: sorry I didn't realize someone posted the solution. Anyways it seems to me that the proof can be more complete if you point out why the inequalities hold hence the $x>-1$ is a little bit tricky.

Comment: i will post now